# 'map' object is not subscriptable,How to extract a part of map

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

```
     66         test_indexes = set(random.sample(indexes, len(indexes)//2)) # removing 50% edges from test data
     67         train_indexes = set(indexes).difference(test_indexes)
---> 68         test_list = [edge_list[i] for i in test_indexes]
     69         train_list = [edge_list[i] for i in train_indexes]
     70         return train_list,test_list
```

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

I want to know how to take part of edgelist (which is a map) into test_list>Please help me with this

Comment: Please post complete runnable code including sample inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe that given the information, at some point you may have tried to create a list (edge_list) by mapping a function to another list using map. Please take the following as an example.

```
lst = [1,2,3]
new_lst = map(lambda x: x**2, lst)
type(new_lst)
```

This returns a 'map' object which is not iterable. Try casting the new_lst in this example, the edge_list in yours, to a list by:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
new_lst = list(map(lambda x: x**2, lst))
type(new_lst)
```

Comment: edge_list is done by using the following code:

Comment: edge_list = map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split())), data_file.read().split("\n")[:-1])

Comment: In that case yes the issue is that the type of edge_list is 'map', and not list as you are expecting. Casting the map object to list as I have shown should fix the issue!

Comment: test_list = list(map([edge_list[i] for i in test_indexes]))
    train_list = list(map([edge_list[i] for i in train_indexes]))

Comment: Above code gives the same error after changing the type

Comment: Yep because that's still incorrect, you need to do it in your assignment of edge_list as per my answer:

edge_list = list(map(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split())), data_file.read().split("\n")[:-1]))

Your assignment of train and test list will be fine once the type of edge_list is list.